# Webcam implementation in flutter_mobile_vision package

Tags: flutter, computer-vision, webcam, flutter-web, google-mlkit

I am a beginner in Flutter and started working on projects implementing text recognition in live video stream. I used flutter_mobile_vision package for the same but the problem is that I am unable to get video stream for analysis when I tried to use external USB webcam in the project.

Can anyone suggest me a way to implement webcam for this package?

Comment: Google Mobile Vision is now part of the ML Kit (g.co/mlkit). The direct usage of Google Mobile Vision is deprecated now. ML Kit provides platform-specfic APIs on Android and iOS and you may be able to call it from Flutter following this dev doc: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

ML Kit's text recognition: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition

Comment: @DongChen I already knew that Google Mobile Vision is now part of ML kit but my issue is here that external USB webcams can't be accessed by any of Mobile Vision modules.

Comment: have you found a way to use a USB camera in a flutter?